# Inconsistency with scala reflection library

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, parameterized, mirror

I'm having trouble understanding why using scala's runtime reflection in 2.11.1 gives me seemingly inconsistent results.

I am trying to inspect the type of a field contained in a java object, like this one:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example {
  private List<Integer> listOfInts;

  public Example () {
    listOfInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }  
}
```

Now suppose I have a scala program that tries to reason about the type of the field inside "Example:"

```
import java.lang.Class
import java.lang.reflect.Field
import java.util.List
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => ru }

object Inspect extends scala.App {
  val example = new Example 
  val cls = example.getClass
  val listfield = cls.getDeclaredField("listOfInts")

  println(isListType(listfield)) // prints false 
  println(isListType(listfield)) // prints true, as do all subsequent calls

  def isListType (field: Field): Boolean = {
    /*
      A function that returns whether the type of the field is a list.
      Based on examples at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html
    */
    val fieldcls = field.getType

    val mirror: ru.Mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val fieldsym: ru.ClassSymbol = mirror.classSymbol(fieldcls)
    val fieldtype: ru.Type = fieldsym.toType 

    (fieldtype <:< ru.typeOf[List[_]])
  }  
}
```

In this particular code snippet, the first call to isListType returns false, and the second returns true. If I switch the type operator from `<:<` to `=:=`, the first call returns true, and the second false.

I have a similar function in a larger code body, and have found that even when the function is part of a static object, this behavior occurs. This does not happen when using unparameterized classes. While I intended for the function to be pure, this is obviously not the case. Further experimentation has shown that there is some persistent state held somewhere. If I replace the `isListType` function with straightline code, I get this:

```
...
val example = new Example   
val cls = example.getClass
val listfield = cls.getDeclaredField("listOfInts")
val fieldcls = listfield.getType

val mirror: ru.Mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val fieldsym: ru.ClassSymbol = mirror.classSymbol(fieldcls)
val fieldtype: ru.Type = fieldsym.toType 

println(fieldtype <:< ru.typeOf[List[_]]) // prints false
println(fieldtype <:< ru.typeOf[List[_]]) // prints false
```

but if I reassign to field type after the `<:<` operator, I get this:

```
// replace as under the fieldsym assignment
var fieldtype: ru.Type = fieldsym.toType 
println(fieldtype <:< ru.typeOf[List[_]]) // prints false

fieldtype = fieldsym.toType 
println(fieldtype <:< ru.typeOf[List[_]]) // prints true
```

while reassigning to field type before the `<:<` operator gives this:

```
// replace as under the fieldsym assignment
var fieldtype: ru.Type = fieldsym.toType 
fieldtype = fieldsym.toType 

println(fieldtype <:< ru.typeOf[List[_]]) // prints false
println(fieldtype <:< ru.typeOf[List[_]]) // prints false
```

Does anyone understand what I'm doing wrong here, or at least have a way around this?

Comment: Api is experimental, check with scala 2.11.2 - and then create issue `http://scala-lang.org/contribute/bug-reporting-guide.html`

Comment: Looks like a bug, I'll try to take a look soon.

Answer (score 2):

The reflection library is based on the compiler, which is a crying shame. People should demand better. Anyway, this is just how it is.

Here's a sample ticket from almost two years ago. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6826

> there is some persistent state held somewhere

There's almost nothing but.

Addendum: for a truly dizzying experience, page through a selection of the 355 [open reflection](https://issues.scala-lang.org/issues/?jql=status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20text%20~%20reflection%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC) tickets.

Comment: Someone must have downvoted because you didn't pun along the lines of, "On further reflection,...". But the ticket comment adds, "Calling toString sometimes leads to normalize being called (that is a bug, which I might have fixed in master, can't remember) which can force the info." I was laughing at (or with, I guess) "I guess this is something that shouldn't have happened." but then I saw you already pull-quoted it.

Comment: OK, just noticed `JavaMirror extends FunHouseMirror`.

Comment: Man, you made me check.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about mixing Java reflection and Scala reflection, but symbols do need initialization, as I remember past issues around lack thereof.  Surely the re-assignment is not relevant, but maybe after the first `<:<` the state of the Symbol changes.

usage:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime._ ; import universe._
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._

scala> typeOf[jex.Example]
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = jex.Example

scala> .declarations
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope = SynchronizedOps(variable listOfInts, constructor Example)

scala> typeOf[jex.Example] member (TermName("listOfInts"))
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = variable listOfInts

scala> .typeSignature
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = java.util.List[Integer]
```

Sorry if I'm too distracted to read your question correctly.

Here's my attempt to reproduce:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime._ ; import universe._
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._

scala> classOf[jex.Example].getDeclaredField("listOfInts").getType
res0: Class[_] = interface java.util.List

scala> currentMirror classSymbol res0 toType
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = java.util.List

scala> .<:<(typeOf[List[_]])
res2: Boolean = false

scala> currentMirror classSymbol res0 toType
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = java.util.List[E]

scala> .<:<(typeOf[List[_]])
res4: Boolean = false
```

Another attempt:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime._ ; import universe._
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._

scala> val x = new jex.Example
x: jex.Example = jex.Example@1efed156

scala> x.getClass getDeclaredField "listOfInts" getType
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res0: Class[_] = interface java.util.List

scala> val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
m: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader@1ffd0e4b of type class scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader with classpath [(memory)] and parent being scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@3b084709 of type class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader with classpath [file:/home/apm/jdk-8/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/resources.jar,file:/home/apm/jdk-8/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/rt.jar,file:/home/apm/jdk-8/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/jsse.jar,file:/home/apm/jdk-8/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/jce.jar,file:/home/apm/jdk-8/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/charsets.jar,file:/home/apm/jdk-8/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/jfr.jar,file:/home/apm/scala-2.11.2/lib/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar,file:/home/apm/scala-2.11.2/lib/config-1.2...
scala> val s = m classSymbol res0
s: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol = trait List

scala> var t = s.toType
t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = java.util.List[E]

scala> t <:< typeOf[List[_]]
res1: Boolean = false

scala> t = s.toType
t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = java.util.List[E]

scala> t <:< typeOf[List[_]]
res2: Boolean = false
```

OK, so I verified your test class.  If the REPL behaves differently, it's probably due to side effects because of printing results.

So adding this to your test

```
val fieldsym: ru.ClassSymbol = mirror.classSymbol(fieldcls)
println(fieldsym)
val fieldtype: ru.Type = fieldsym.toType
println(fieldtype)
```

fixes the issue.

```
apm@mara:~/tmp$ vi jex/inspect.scala
apm@mara:~/tmp$ scalac jex/inspect.scala && scala jex.Inspect
false
true
apm@mara:~/tmp$ vi jex/inspect.scala
apm@mara:~/tmp$ scalac jex/inspect.scala && scala jex.Inspect
trait List
java.util.List[E]
true
trait List
java.util.List[E]
true
```

I don't know if there's a lesson about "initialize your Syms!"

"At Syms, an educated consumer is our best customer."