# Inconsistent result when checking type subtype

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

Sometimes I get inconsistent result when I check if a class extends a trait. I'm using scala 2.12.8.

My project uses `ru.Type` to dynamically build a chain of operations. The output of an operation must conform to the input of the next one.

Before linking two operations, I check if type are compatible using:

```scala
def checkFrom(t: ru.Type): Boolean = t <:< ru.typeOf[ExpectedTrait[_, _, _]]
```

But sometimes (rarely in fact), `<:<` returns false instead true (I didn't identify the cause).
I've added debug message:

```
def checkFrom(t: ru.Type): Boolean = {
  val expectedType = ru.typeOf[ExpectedTrait[_, _, _]]
  val r = t <:< expectedType
  if (!r) println(s"$t is not a $expectedType (${t <:< expectedType})")
  r
}
```

I can see message like: `MyClass is not a ExpectedTrait (true)`.
The first evaluation of `<:<` returns false and the second returns true !

t is an `Types$ClassNoArtgsTypeRef` and expectedType is a `Types$ExistentialType`

--edit-1--

All ru.Type come from `ru.typeOf[X]`. In this case, I don't use `rm.classSymbol(x.getClass).toType`.

This issue is probably related to [inconsistency-with-scala-reflection-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371933/inconsistency-with-scala-reflection-library)

Does it exist a workaround ?

--edit-2--

I can reproduce the error with the following code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

abstract class BaseClass[A, This <: BaseClass[A, This]](a: A) {
  def newInstance(a: A): This
}

abstract class ExtClass[A, This <: ExtClass[A, This]](a: A) extends BaseClass[A, This](a)

class MyClass(n: Int) extends ExtClass[Int, MyClass](n) {
  override def newInstance(a: Int): MyClass = new MyClass(a)
}

object ReflectionTest extends App {
  def test[T: ru.TypeTag](tpe: ru.Type): Boolean = {
    val r = tpe <:< ru.typeOf[T]
    if (!r) println(s"test fails: ${tpe <:< ru.typeOf[T]}")
    r
  }
  println((0 until 1000).par.forall(_ => test[BaseClass[_, _]](ru.typeOf[MyClass])))
}
```

I think the key point is the parallel execution. Here an example of output:

```
test fails: true
test fails: true
false
```

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce.

Comment: Even with my example code ? For me, 20% of its run fails, on average.

Comment: Yes, now I can, thanks.

Comment: Originally Scala reflection wasn't thread-safe. https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/thread-safety.html Since 2.11 it is considered as thread-safe but apparently sometimes still is not.